# "wish you have sweet dreams" and "hope you have sweet dreams" -- are they grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, wish

I hear people say, or read people write, stuff like:

> (I/we) Wish you have sweet dreams
>
> (I/we) Wish you have a good day
>
> (I/we are?) Wishing you have a Happy New Year!

are these grammatical? Why or why not?

What if the verb "hope" is used instead of wish in those sentences?

> (I/we) Hope you have sweet dreams
>
> (I/we) Hope you have a good day
>
> (I/we are?) Hoping you have a Happy New Year!

Are they grammatical? Why or why not?

Comment: I usually see/hear versions that favor brevity: _Happy New Year! Have a good day! Sweet dreams!_ The "I hope you have" (or "I'm wishing you") part is generally impied, not explicitly stated.

Comment: "Hoping you have a Happy New Year!" and "Wishing you a Happy New Year!" both sound normal to me (although more likely to be written than spoken.) "Hope you have a good day" also sounds fine. "Wish you have a good day" sounds odd to me, and I'm surprised you've heard people using  "wish" like this.

Answer (score 1):

In the phrases with "wish" you have to delete "have" So:

I/we) wish you  sweet dreams

(I/we) wish you  a good day

Wishing you  a happy New Year! or 
I/ we wish you a happy New Year       (the difference between these is a separate question)

But you could also say:

Have sweet dreams!
Have a good day!
Have a happy New Year!

Best of all because most commonly used, is to delete BOTH verbs. So:

Sweet dreams!!!!!
Happy New Year!!!!! although for some reason
"Have a good day" is best with "have"

I'm not very good at "why". This is what people say.

All the alternatives with "hope" are grammatically correct. Your choice of which one to say would depend on the situation